# using md5sum to remove identical duplicate files

Tags: linux

```
find -type f -exec md5sum '{}' ';' | uniq --all-repeated=separate -w 33 | cut -c 35-
```

I am trying to use md5sum to remove files that have exactly the same content in a certain directory, to put in at the end of my bash file. the code above I came across when trying to research md5sum but it is for uniq and I am using puppyware. Also I am very new to linux, so I probably have missed something in that line of code there.

EDIT: is there any other way to get unique files?

Answer (score 4):

You could use fdupes (`sudo apt-get install fdupes`)
It does all the work.

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines (untested):

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar nullglob
shopt -u failglob

declare -A files=()
declare -A nbHash=()

for f in **; do
    [[ -f "$f" ]] || continue
    md5sum=$(md5sum -- "$f")
    files[$f]=$md5sum
    ((nbHash[$md5sum]+=1))
done

for f in "${!files[@]}"; do
    if ((nbHash[${files[$f]}]-->1)); then
        rm -- "$f"
    fi
done
```

Make 2 associative arrays:

- `files`: the keys are the file names, the values are the md5sum
- `nbHash`: the keys are the md5sum, the values are the number of files with md5sum

After you've done these associative arrays, loop through files (i.e., through the keys of array `files`), and determine if there's more than one file with same md5sum (you have this information from the `nbHash` array), and if so, rm the file.

Comment: it didn't like globstar or the arrays

Comment: @user2984284 Why not? that's the bash way! `:)`. Without globstar and arrays, bash is not bash.

Comment: I'm adding it to other code in a bash file, should I keep this code clumped together in it?

Comment: oh mines is a shell script sorry

Comment: @user2984284 by shell script, you mean it starts with `#!/bin/sh`? if it's the case, you should remove the `bash` tag from your question and retag it appropriately.